# action and object graph api queries?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I can submit custom {action}/{object} to the facebook graph api succesfully.

I''m wondering if there is a way I could query the graph api for all {objects}/{actions}?

For example i want to retrieve a list of all {objects} that have been made using my facebook app?
And I want to get the user that originally created the {object}
Also I want to get the users that have took {action} on a specific {object{
etc

I hope I'm being clear... For example consider facebook recipe's example:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/

I'd like to query for a list of users who have "cooked" a specific "recipe"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to query for a list of users who have "cooked" a specific "recipe"

AFAIK there is no way to do that; you can only query an individual user for `/me/namespace:action`, to see which actions they have published.

> And I want to get the user that originally created the {object} Also I want to get the users that have took {action} on a specific {object{ etc

Then your best way to go is to save that kind of information to your own database, at the point when these actions happen.